# which format Facebook return for timezone field in User Profile API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, timezone

I am developing a Facebook chatbot and when I query for user profile data I get user timezone as +2

but what formate does Facebook return if the timezone is `1:15` is it `+1:15` or `+1.25` https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/difference.html?p1=1440

I did not find a way to change my timezone or test users timezone to test it.

also the list if timezone ids is not helpful https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/timezone-ids/v2.9

User profile api https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/user-profile

Comment: Docs for User Profile API just describes the field as “Timezone, number relative to GMT” - but I think it is reasonable to believe that you will get exactly the same as you would from the [Graph API User object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/), and there it says, “float (min: -24) (max: 24)”. So I am pretty sure that for an actual time zone offset of `1:15` you should get back `1.15` here.

Comment: I agree with you, note I think for 1:15 I should expect 1.25 as the 15 min = 25% of hour

Comment: Yeah, that would be the alternative, not sure which one it will be to be honest. I'd try changing my location on the user profile to one that has such an "odd" timezone, hoping that will yield a usable test result. (I don't think you can do that with a test user, since all locations are essentially pages, and test users can not interact with real pages in any way.)

Comment: Although, assuming the theoretical possibility that one day some rogue territory of wherever might decide to go with a timezone offset, of say X hours and 27 minutes (if only to mess with the rest of the world), it would make much more sense to return that as `X.27` instead of `X.41666666666...`, because floating point imprecision is gonna bite anyone who actually wants to do anything with that timezone value sooner or later ...